# Installing MariaDB on Ubuntu 18.04 WSL - ISSUE System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate

Tags: linux, mariadb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to install mariaDB v 10.4 onto the Ubuntu 18.04 WSL linux subsystem, but can not get the mysql service to start. During the install I get the following error:

> System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't
>   operate.

When I try to manually start the service I get the following error:

> mysql: unrecognized service

I am at a complete loss of where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appricated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your Ubuntu 18.04 was not started with the default init system, which is `systemd` nowadays. Maybe your system uses an alternative init system, for example `sysvinit` or `upstart`. Analyzing the latest MariaDB 10.4 server package for Ubuntu 18.04 (mariadb-server-10.4_10.4.10+maria~bionic_amd64.deb), the package seems to be relying only on the systemd init system. There are no legacy init scripts added in the package either.

Means you have two possibilities: Either install systemd and use it as init system (using `systemd-sysv` package) or create your own init script based on an older version of MariaDB. Here's the init script from MariaDB 10.2 package as reference: https://gist.github.com/Napsty/b8ee4364d710518a958bf0ad12267757

Comment: From what I have found searching Microsoft is using its own init system for Linux installed under WSL. Looking at the init script you referenced do you think a third option would be installing MariaDB v10.2?

Comment: Unless there are MariaDB packages specifically built for WSL (and I could not find an offiical MariaDB repository), your suggestion may work, yes. However note that according to https://mariadb.org/about/maintenance-policy/, 10.2 will be EOL in 2022 (still might give you happy 2.5 years ;-) ).

Comment: Bummer. I thought that would be a good solution as it did work to complete the install and create a user however starting the service just states "fail" after about 90 seconds.

Comment: Ok it looks like the issue was two fold. 1) You hit it on the head 10.4 is not currently compatible with WSL. 10.2.29 is the latest version I was able to successfully install. 2) It would not start because I also had the windows version installed and running on the same port 3306. Once I changed that it started fine. Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you provide insight into how you achieved point 2? Specifically about the port?